# Skip Jenkins Stage if its last excution was successfull

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for way to speed up our Build-Pipeline.
The biggest impact would be to do certain things only if they have not been done.

So basically, I have already parameterized some optional stages which works fine, but there are some things I'd like to skip if there was a execution before which was successfull.

I have searched the docs, especially the section ref. [`when`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) but the was nothing that did the job.

So the question is: Is there something I can do in a declarative pipeline to always skip a stage, except when

1. It has never been run successfully before
2. The last time it ran was not successful (eg. if I allow for its execution to be forced by passing a parameter)

I though about using the Build Number (eg only run it on the first execution of the pipeline), but this does't cut it for 2 reasons

1. I'm using milestones to prevent multiple executions of the pipe for a given branch/PR
2. If the first run fails, it would never be tried again

Oh, and I also thought about putting all of the logic in post -> regression and forcing the stage to fail on the first pipeline run, but this doesn't seem to be a good idea either.

Comment: What about using the global environment variables to save the state you need? it can solve your issue, however it get can get a bit messy if you want to save the state for many parameters.

Comment: @NoamHelmer I have researched but I didn't find anything: is it possible to add new global environment Variables from a Pipeline or do they have to exist prior to each job run?

Comment: I will add an example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option ,although not ideal for large scale, can be to store the diffrent states as Global Environment Variables. (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables).
These parameters are available for all jobs and can store parameters in a 'server wide' scope.
You can then update or set them via code using the following groovy method:

```
@NonCPS
def updateGlobalEnvVariable(String name, String value) {
    def globalNodeProperties = Jenkins.getInstance().getGlobalNodeProperties()
    def envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

    if (envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0) {
        def envVarsNodePropertyClass = this.class.classLoader.loadClass('hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty')
        globalNodeProperties.add(envVarsNodePropertyClass.newInstance())
    }
    envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars().put(name, value)
}
```

This function will create the parameter if it does not exists or update its value in case it already exists. Also this function should better be placed in a **Shared Library** from which it will be available for all pipelines.

A nice advantage for this technique is that you can always 'reset' the different stages from the configuration page, However if you need to store multiple stages it can overflow the configuration page with a bit too much information.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I'm not too concerned about Information overload. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [custom shared-workspace](https://plugins.jenkins.io/shared-workspace/) and then create/store some state file or something that could be used by your next executions like lastexecfailed.state and then try to locate the file on the shared workspace at the beginning of your execution.

Comment: I ended up using another approach, but I'm pretty sure your suggestion would work for many (if not for me). You gave me the Idea to examine using EnvInject with prop-files which would have solved my issue too (multibranch, shared workspace was not an option due to some limitations on our side projectwise). Thank you, and enjoy your upvote! Apprechiated your answer!